# How to remove long description navigation from MessageItem control

Tags: css, sapui5

I'm creating a message popover that acts as a chat window (See image below)
[image]

By default, if the MessageItem control has a text description that is larger than the window, the user can click on the message and UI5 will use a slide navigation to show the complete description. Here is a [sample](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#/sample/sap.m.sample.MessagePopover/preview) from the docs of this behavior (click on the information button on the bottom of the sample)

Rather than navigate the user to a long description view, I want to simply wrap any long text description to the next line. Is there a way to implement this functionality? I know this is possible with pure CSS, but I don't want to fight the out of box UI5 control if there is a cleaner way of doing this?

Edit: The code is pretty generic

```
    this.oMessageItemTemplate = new MessageItem({
        type: "{namedModel>type}",
        title: "{namedModel>message}",
        description: "{namedModel>description}",
        longtextUrl: "{namedModel>longtextUrl}"
    });
```

Comment: why arent you using the i18n model for your texts?

Comment: i don't think there is an other option than pure css here

Comment: You'll probably have to fight the control... Have you considered using the [Feed](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/sample/sap.m.sample.Feed/preview) controls instead?

Comment: That's unfortunately the only solution I was able to do.

Comment: @Erch, this is a POC, not a best practice app...